# RedisJson: not able to find exact tree structure

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redisearch, redisjson

we have array of objects which we are storing in RedisJson. object looks like this

```
[
   {
       "abcd": null,
       "pqrs": "002090618000132",
       "xyz":"SomeValue2",
       "mnop": 5,
       "Properties": {
           "property1": "04240424",
           "property2": "04240424",
           "property3": "04240424"
       },
       "Alarms": {}
   },
   {
       "abcd": null,
       "pqrs": "002090618000132",
       "xyz":"SomeValue3",
       "mnop": 5,
       "Properties": {
           "property1": "04240424",
           "property2": "04240424",
           "property3": "04240424"
       },
       "Alarms": {}
   }
]
```

I need to find out all elements in given array where **xyz==SomeValue2**. I tried multiple things, however, did not worked for me.

Query I am trying to filter the above data is

```
json.get SomeKey $[?(xyz==SomeValue2)]

Also tried

json.get SomeKey $.[?(xyz==SomeValue2)]

also

json.get SomeKey $[?(@.xyz==SomeValue2)]
```

everytime I am getting below error

> "JSON Path error: path error: \n$[?(xyz==SomeValue2)]\n^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n"

Somehow I am not able to get to the exact tree structure what redis is following

When I tried to get data without filter I am getting it

`json.get SomeKey $[0]`

`json.get SomeKey $[0].xyz`

Please suggest what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the entire path, and quote the string value

```
JSON.GET SomeKey '$[?(@.xyz=="SomeValue2")]'
```